# roscd only finding rosbuild packages

Tags: ros, catkin, roscd, package, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm on Groovy/Ubuntu 12.04. Yesterday I installed the stand alone install of Gazebo because they no longer support the older version of Gazebo that comes with ROS. It also required that I install Fuerte debians because it still has some of those dependencies. I've heard that different version of ROS can be installed along side each other so long as you only source one. But the problem is that now roscd only can find rosbuild packages - ones with manifest.xml files in them. I confirmed this with ROS, MoveIt and my own packages. Am I correct in assuming that this is because Fuerte is also installed on my computer?

According to [Gazebo's website](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.3/install):

> ROS Users: Only install Gazebo from
> here. Never use the instruction on the
> ros.org website.

So that is what I did.

**Update:**
It appears roscd stops working correctly after I run

```
rosrun urdf_parser check_urdf robot.urdf
[rospack] Error: stack/package urdf_parser not found
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named check_urdf below
```

Is this at all possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52391/roscd-only-finding-rosbuild-packages/) by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1396 on 2013-01-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-01-15**:
To help find and fix this, can you report the exact steps you did in a ticket at https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues. Explain where you source which setup.sh (.bashrc?), and then what commands you run in the terminal until roscd misbehaves.

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2013-01-22**:
The solution I found was to just not sure the Gazebo 1.3 debian, uninstalling along with it all of Gazebo's Fuerte dependencies. When I do that everything works - with the same setup.sh stuff as instructed in the catkin workspace instructions. I'm going to give Gazebo some time to adjust to Groovy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I think I've figured it out:

1. urdf_parser is depreciated in Groovy, but this is not documented on its [wiki page](http://ros.org/wiki/urdf_parser?distro=fuerte)
2. The latest version of Gazebo (1.3) still requires ros-fuerte-urdfdom, so I had this on my system as well
3. Somehow when I do `rosrun urdf_parser check_urdf robot.urdf` it confused my computer into no longer understanding catkin packages, essentially throwing it into "fuerte" mode

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2013-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-01-15**:
The wiki is also free for you to edit, to help other users following in your footsteps. rosrun cannot change the environment, at worst it could have some impact on the rospack cache, which would be a serious bug to fix.

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2013-01-22**:
I tried to edit the wiki but there is no section for Groovy (no button at the top)

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-01-23**:
the buttons are generated by a special macro that you can insert yourself. Just llok at the page source for a page with the buttons.

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2013-01-25**:
I added a note about the change, but I don't know enough about the new urdfdom to write the documentation. They seem to have changed packages entirely.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roscd does support catkin packages. On a clean installation (with no old versions of tools installed via PIP) after sourcing /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash the command "roscd roscpp" brings you to /opt/ros/groovy/share/roscpp.

So double check that you have the latest version from all the tools installed and no old PIP packages.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-01-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2013-01-15**:
I believe I do have the latest everything